# Javascript Combine 2 regexes

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a couple of regex which I am planning to combine.
So the first regex is as below (allows amounts with particular thousand and decimal separators)

```
"^-?(\\d+|\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3})*)?(\\.(\\d+)?)?$"
```

I have similar other regexes (based on different locales e.g. other one would have comma as the decimal separator)

So with the above regex, following are Valid/Invalid values

```
123.11 (Valid)
1'23 (Invalid)
```

With the second regex, I want that the string can contain a max of 13 digits (including before or after the decimal)

```
^[^\\d]*?(\\d|\\d[^\\d]+){0,13}$
```

With the above regex, following are Valid/Invalid values

```
1234567890123 (Valid - 13 digits)
12345678901234 (Invalid - 14 digits)
1234567890.123 (Valid as 13 digits...10.3)
1234567890.1234 (Invalid as 14 digits...10.4)
```

Is it possible to somehow consolidate the 2 regex? 
However, I do not want to touch the first regex (have different combinations based on different locales). But it would be nice to somehow dynamically append the 2nd regex into the first one ?

So, I am flexible with the 2nd regex as that is not based on any locale, but is going to be the same always and mainly validates for max of 13 digits in the string.

I'll then validate my string using the consolidated regex.

Comment: coz, otherwise I have to write some additional logic to validate against 2 separate regexes in my common regex validation method currently....I am trying to not touch that method and instead have a consolidated regex to validate against...

Comment: Why not just do `regex1.test(value) && regex2.test(value)`? I don't see why you'd want to dynamically combine them. It's possible but error prone and much more difficult than simply using the two.

Comment: Actually, there are lot of things ....but i am using a cp validation library and setup my objects and then have a common/custom regex mixin where I have the logic...so, a bit difficult to explain why I cannot just do a direct && check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may keep the first pattern as is, and just prepend it with

```
(?=^\D*(?:\d\D*){0,13}$)
```

The `(?=^\D*(?:\d\D*){0,13}$)` pattern represents a *positive lookahead* that matches a location that is immediately followed with

- `^` - start of string
- `\D*` - 0+ non-digits
- `(?:\d\D*){0,13}` - 0 to 13 occurrences of a digit followed with a non-digit char
- `$` - end of string.

Full JavaScript regex definition:

```
var regex1 = "^-?(\\d+|\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3})*)?(\\.(\\d+)?)?$";     // Not to be touched
var consolidated_regex = "(?=^\\D*(?:\\d\\D*){0,13}$)" + regex1;
```

See [full regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fRM4HR/1).

**Details**

Comment: Awesome...This seems to be exactly what I was looking for...I'll test out all the values now...But again, this seems perfect. Thanks

Comment: seems to be my answer, yes ?

Comment: @Edward No, it is far from your pattern. It has no redundant `(?=.)` lookahead, contains a more efficient `\D` construct to match any non-digit chars, shows a technique how to keep one pattern and restrict it with another without chaning the first regex.

Comment: fancy, engines `\D` is replaced by its class `[^\d]` upon compile. `(?=.)` was a leftover for  `(?=[^\d]*(?:\d[^\d]*){0,13}$)`  is a guarantees a character exists when he uses follower expressions that have all optional terms where OP doesnt know better. I changed it to `(?=[^\d]*(?:\d[^\d]*){1,13}$)` who cares if it was left in. Finaly, there is _trgex technique_ to combine my pattern with another on, ots called string concatenation. And the correct english word is prefix not prepend.